# SQL: Design database to reflect tournament design

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to make a simple tournament system, and now I've come to another wall...
I have a Table named `Teams` - Each `Team` can participate in multiple matches.

I've thought about having a table named `Matches` which have 4 columns:

> - ID        => Identifier
> - Team1ID   => Reference to ID in Teams
> - Team2ID   => Reference to ID in Teams
> - WinnerID  => Same value as either Team1ID or Team2ID

`WinnerID` will then have a sql trigger that checks whether its the same value as `Team1ID` or `Team2ID`... If not it will rollback the transaction.

This approach seemed perfect in the start, until I realized that it broke several "best practice" rules, including the *"repository per aggregate root"* because it would require me to do:

```
Team myTeam1 = ... Get team1 ...
Team myTeam2 = ... Get team2 ...

Match myMatch = new Match { Team1 = myteam1, Team2 = myteam2; }
```

which is wrong since the `Match` entity is defined as a "child entity" for the `Team` entity, and should only be added through the `Team` entity.

Any suggestions about how to design my database properly to fit my needs?

Comment: I don't know if I agree with the statement "Match is a child entity for Team". While the two are related, it seems that Matches will need independent retrieval. I'd be wary of over-thinking your design to satisfy DDD principles.

Comment: @John Bledsoe, well.. the Match entity depends on Team, since it requires 2 Team entities referenced..

Comment: You're right of course, but what I mean is that you may want to get matches in ways other than "Give me all the matches for team X." In that case you're going to need something other than the team aggregate  root to retrieve matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the trigger, I would just use some constraints.

```
(Team1ID <> Team2ID)
AND
(WinnerID IS NULL OR Team1ID = WinnerID OR Team2ID = WinnerID)
```

probably all in one constraint.

As far as the domain model, I would not have thought you add a match through a team, but perhaps through a tournament instance: Match = Tournament.NewMatch(Team1, Team2) ;

Conceivably, there would be higher order tournament rules, like rounds, eliminations, etc.

Since it sounds like your Teams know their Cup, then to create a Team or retrieve it from the database, it would go through the Cup: Cup.NewTeam(TeamName) or Cup.LoadTeam(TeamID).  It would still make sense then for Cup.NewMatch, since you certainly wouldn't want to have a match between teams in different Cups.

Comment: My fault.. I suck to explain - my tournament is more a "cup".. the user just signs up with a team name and the name of 4 other players - The team will only be used within the active cup and should not be available for next cup. The `Team` table has a column named `CupID` which has a reference to the `Cup` table, and that way I can identifiy which teams is in the active cup

Comment: @ebb Added some comments.  I still think your Cup needs a management entity and the Cup entity itself is fine for that.  I've often had designs like that - for instance Meeting and Attendee, where there are multiple meetings (conferences) with registrations and attendees can attend different ones over the years, but the meeting handles the relationship.

Comment: @Cade Roux - I see.. but my `Match` table would still need references to the `Team` table in order to validate the `Team1ID` and `Team2ID` right?

Comment: Yes, I don't see a problem with that.  That's the correct database design.  How to identify the winner, I'm not sure what the correct design for that is yet.  Also you might want to enforce Team1ID < Team2ID to eliminate redundant incorrect symmetrical matches.  (Although there may be a concept of Home/Away team - in which case, they really aren't symmetrical.)

Comment: @Cade Roux - in short: Let the `Match` table be child of  the `Cup` table and Reference the Team table from `Match` too?

Comment: @ebb There is no concept of child in relational databases.  There are only foreign key constraints.  I would have a Match refer to a Cup and a Match refer to two Teams.  I would not have the Teams refer to a Cup.  I would have a CupTeam table which registers Teams to participate in a Cup (so before there are any matches you would still know the participants) - which would have foreign keys to Cup and Team (a classic link table).

Comment: @Cade Roux - sorry for the late answer.. Your approach seems interesting, however I cant figure out how to get all the Matches for a specific team without querying the `Matches` table twice to check both in the `Team1ID` and `Team2ID`

Comment: @ebb Naively, SELECT * FROM Matches WHERE @TeamID IN (Team1ID, Team2ID), where @TeamID is the team you are interested in, but there are a lot of ways to skin that cat, including UNIONs and normalizing with a CASE so the opposing teams are all in one column.

Comment: @Cade Roux - I see... But would it be wrong to create a many-to-many relationship between the Matches and Teams so I have a table named TeamsInMatches? - It would blow the idea of having a maximum of 1 team vs 1 team but I guess a trigger can control that.. What do you think?

Comment: @ebb It's certainly possible to have a TeamsInMatches.  SQL Server doesn't support deferred constraints, so you would probably have difficulty ensuring exactly two teams in each match.  I probably would not do a many-to-many teams to matches.

Answer (score 0):

How would your model store a draw match? :)

Why not store the score in a match row and just determine the winner based on that?

Id, Team1Id, Team2Id, Team1PointsScored, Team2PointsScored

Comment: The match cant be draw, since there's rules for what to do if draw. All I need is whether Team1 or Team2 won in a match. The problem is just how to design the table for it.

Comment: OK, then how about a bit column called IsTeam1Winner?

Comment: I fail to explain... as described in my post, then I'm just wondering whether to let the `Match` table reference the `Team` table, and in my code violate the repository per aggregate principle since the `Match` entity wont be a child entity of `Team`.